# MVC3 Using Javascript to postback similar to how $.post works -- but with an actual postback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3, postback

I have an ASP.NET MVC3 app that features a form with a nested-table input

(Ie on each row I can add a sub-table, with no limit on depth)

To handle this for my MVC app, I've created 2 javascript classes(using this term loosely with js:) that mirror my MVC3 model and post the data to an action method. Everything works great...Except that right now the only way that I know how to do this is with jquery $.ajax or $.post --- How can I do a postback in javascript?

I have the URL, and the custom JSON data, and want to do a page postback... Any suggestions? I can't use the normal form submit due to the nested table scenario described above.

Also, I just want to say, that MVC has made this so simple to render! :) For rendering a recursive view did everything without any script required, only on the saving did I need to screw around with json.

**Update**:I guess another solution would be -- can I change the contents of my form data on submit? My method takes a JSON object, is there any way I can stuff that in my request while my form submit is happening normally?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by: "I know how to do this is with jquery $.ajax or $.post --- How can I do a postback in javascript?" -- jQuery's ajax function is 'javascript' - it's essentially a wrapper of the XMLHttpRequest javascript object.

Comment: Right, but its an asynchronous call - I was wondering if I can mimic a normal form submit and do a postback, as opposed to an ajax call.

Comment: This is mostly because theres a decent amount of set-up and initialization on the page, and I believe it would be cleaner to do a fresh reload than trying to juggle re-initializing everything after an ajax call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found that with the MVC3 binding, the table in my form could be normally bound if I named the fields such as Item[0].Children[1].Children[0].FieldA... etc, everything matched up fine without having to convert to javascript objects/json. I changed my code to fix this naming before a form submit, and it binds pretty well without having to do any json calls at all. Less elegant, but I guess it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [XML Http Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_XMLHttpRequest) to do this. This is eventually what jQuery and other JS libraries use.

But why don't you just stick to jQuery AJAX or POST?

Comment: I guess I just wanted it to work like a regular form/submit where the user would get a postback and a fresh page. I understand I can just take the results and load them back in, figured it would be cleaner to just load the page fresh (as if I was using a normal form/submit) on failure

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question, but it seems like what you want to do is post to the same page you are on, which means if you have the URL (and it sounds like you do), you just need to specific that in the $.ajax method? Maybe you can clarify what you mean a little bit for us.

Edit: Per comment suggested looking at http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

Comment: My $.post works, I just wanted to avoid having to load the response back in and have to re run document.ready() stuff. Also, when the submit is successful and the user is moved to another view, none of the scripts that are already loaded for the form entry page are needed anymore.

Comment: Have you looked at this? It might be of use to you. http://jquery.malsup.com/form/